# Show that $\Phi \vDash \psi \Longleftrightarrow \Phi \cup \{\lnot \psi\} \ \text{is not satisfiable}$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, predicate-logic, satisfiability

The main algorithmic problems in logic (in my bachelors CS course) are: $0)$ evaluation problem "Auswertungsproblem", $1)$ equivalence problem, $2)$ logical consequence, $3)$ satisfiability problem and $4)$ validity problem. All of these problems can be reduced to the satisfiability problem or the evaluation problem.

The equivalence problem states: "Given $\varphi, \psi \in AL \ \text{is} \ \varphi \equiv \psi$?". I can reduce this problem to the logical consequence problem because if $\varphi \equiv \psi \Longleftrightarrow \varphi \vDash \psi \land \psi \vDash \varphi$. If we can determine such a consequence then $\varphi$ and $\psi$ are equivalent.

The logical consequence problem states that: "$\text{Given} \ \Phi \subseteq AL \ \text{and } \ \psi \in AL, \ \text{is} \ \Phi \vDash \psi \ \text{valid}$?" We can reduce this problem to the satisfiability problem because we know that $\Phi \vDash \psi \Longleftrightarrow \Phi \cup \{\lnot \psi\} \ \text{is not satisfiable}$.

I'm having a problem with the very last section. Why is "$\Phi \vDash \psi \Longleftrightarrow \Phi \cup \{\lnot \psi\} \ \text{is not satisfiable}$" true? I can't seem to understand how to go about showing this.

I mean the idea for the whole exercise is to understand that instead of solving $5$ different problems, it is more efficient to reduce them to ones that're "easier" to solve.

Comment: I was wondering what books or course notes reveal the relation between the various algorithmic problems in logic? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding the title question:

(i) if $\Phi \vDash \psi$, then $\Phi \cup \{ ¬ \psi \}$ is *unsatisfiable*.

Assume not, i.e. $\Phi \cup \{ ¬ \psi \}$ is *satisfiable*; this means that there is some valuation such that all of $\Phi$'s are TRUE and also $\lnot \psi$ is, i.e. $\psi$ is FALSE, contradicting the fact that $\Phi \vDash \psi$ means: in every valuation where all of $\Phi$'s are TRUE, $\psi$ **must** be TRUE also.

(ii) if $\Phi \cup \{ ¬ \psi \}$ is *unsatisfiable*, then $\Phi \vDash \psi$.

The proof is similar.

---

The body of the question is not very clear, but yes, the various concept are strictly linked.

With the previous result we have showed how to reduce the problem of *logical consequence* [locical implication] to that of satisfiability.

Also *validity* can be so reduced: a formula $\varphi$ is valid iff $\lnot \varphi$ is unsatisfiable.

And also equivalence is: two formulas are *logically equivalent* iff they imply each other.

Comment: when you prove (ii), assume a model of $\Phi$ doesn't satisfy $\phi$, does the model of $\Phi$ have to satisify $\neg \phi$?